# Php 80 for Centos, yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php80, what I do wrong?

Tags: php, centos

On my client's Centos server by defaul is php 7.1 - very old one.
On the panel there is [the instruction](https://jino.ru/help/faq/vps/php-centos/) how to upgrade the version.

I'm on the 5th part of that instruction. I write

```
yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php80 php php-cli
```

But there is some mistake on the screenshot. What I do wrong? What is the correct repository?
At first I thought that maybe there is no php8.0 on the server, tried the same with php7.4, but I see the same mistake.
[image]

Comment: You can't just enable `remi` if you don't have it installed... https://www.2daygeek.com/install-enable-remi-repository-on-centos-rhel-fedora-linux/

Comment: So the instruction is wrong in part 2?  There is installation written as rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum -y install epel-release, but it has to be yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm or yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm?

Comment: Those instructions seem pretty ancient. That said, [Remi 7 _does_ have PHP 8.0 (and 8.1)](https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/). You may want to double-check that you actually have remi properly installed.

Comment: do I have to copy other strings from the instruction, if I write yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm instead of the second part? I do it at first

Comment: I cannot vouch for how well an antique tutorial written in Russian will work for you, or what of it you should skip or not. In my first comment, I've referred you to a post with more up-to-date information, including how to check if Remi is properly installed and enabled.  Just use the [Remi Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) to get the commands you need.

Comment: It helped - one string from your link and all other from there. In general it works now. I still have problems with working of dompdf and zip extension, I think something I lost